# How to delete nested data in dojo data store?

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid

Suppose I have the following:

```
var data = {

   identifier: "pkid",
   items: [ {pkid: 3456, name: "Tom", kids: [ {pkid: 3459, kidname: "Jenny"}, {pkid: 45698, kidname: "Jimmy"} ]
   }

   var mainStore = new ItemFileWriteStore({data: data});  

   var mainGrid = new var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
        id: 'grid',
        store: store,
        structure: layout,
        rowSelector: '20px'},
      document.createElement('div'));

    /*append the new grid to the div*/
    dojo.byId("maingridDiv").appendChild(grid.domNode);

    /*Call startup() to render the grid*/
    grid.startup();
```

How can I delete the kid identified by pkid: 45698 from the data store and it should be reflected in the grid if it was showing that kid, and should not show anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you'll just var kids = store.getValues(parent, "kids");
Then you need to identify at which index is the kid your looking for, then store.setValues(parent, "kids", kids.splice(indexOfKid, 1));
something like that.